# jQuery .append doesn't work on .submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an AJAX function that loads data from the database using a simple `select *` ... to a div. the function works fine without submit, but when I use a form, it doesn't work and the `#itemContainer` is empty, Am I missing something? I even tried :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myForm").submit(function() {
```

but didn't work also

My code :

```html
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $("#myForm").submit(function() {
   $.ajax({
     url: 'models/fetchUsers.php', //the script to call to get data
     dataType: 'json', //data format
     success: function(data) //on recieve of reply
       {
         $.each($(data), function(key, value) {
           $('#itemContainer').append(value.user_id);
         });
       }
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: It's because page will be reloaded on `form.submit()`. Add `return false` to avoid reload.

Comment: you need to add your form data into database using on click event instead of form submit event. because when you submit your form, then your page will be reload/refresh. so your foreach loop not working for the same.

Comment: Thank you @Pugazh, you could post an answer to vote it.

Comment: @user2997418 : I have posted the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't cancel form submission event.

Add `preventDefault()` in your submit

Like this

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'models/fetchUsers.php', //the script to call to get data
    dataType: 'json', //data format
    success: function(data) //on recieve of reply
      {
        $.each($(data), function(key, value) {
          $('#itemContainer').append(value.user_id);
        });
      }
  });
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Update**:

`event.preventDefault()` is depricated.

try to use `return false;`

Like this

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'models/fetchUsers.php', //the script to call to get data
    dataType: 'json', //data format
    success: function(data) //on recieve of reply
      {
        $.each($(data), function(key, value) {
          $('#itemContainer').append(value.user_id);
        });
      }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: preventDefault is depricated, you can use return false instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Prateik

Answer (score 0):

It's because page will be reloaded on form submission.

Handle the submit event and add `return false`.

```html
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $("#myForm").submit(function() {
    submitForm();
    return false;
  });

  function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'models/fetchUsers.php', //the script to call to get data
      dataType: 'json', //data format
      success: function(data) //on recieve of reply
        {
          $.each($(data), function(key, value) {
            $('#itemContainer').append(value.user_id);
          });
        }
    });

  };
</script>
```